# Radiometrically correct one UAV image

Tags: r, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, pix4d

Does anyone out there know how to perform radiometric corrections on a single image taken with a multispectral sensor?

I know there is proprietary software (such as PiX4D) that can do this; however, they can only process images in series (which I don't have and can't obtain).

Comment: What is your objective with the radiometric correction?

Comment: @Aaron I will like to reduce/correct the errors on some digital numbers that I extracted from some images. I know for a fact that the extracted values that I have (from the non corrected images) are higher. My first idea was that maybe those higher values are being cause because I am not radiometrically correcting my images.

Comment: Are you working with multiple images acquired at different time periods or a single image? Also what you hope to use the imagery for matters in determining methods for radiometric calibration.

Comment: There is this for a Micasense RedEdge.  I have never tied it. Some skills at Python programming will be required. https://support.micasense.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000351194-RedEdge-Camera-Radiometric-Calibration-Model

Comment: Did you take before/after photos with a calibration pad? Without known reflectance values I'm not sure you're going to have much luck with this.

Comment: @JepsonNomad yes I took before and after photos of my calibration panel.

Comment: @Aaron I am working with multiple images collected during a 15 min interval. But for right now I am trying to calibrate one and them do the rest.